# How to load kernel modules for docker container without privileged mode?

Tags: docker

I would like to use some functions like fuse (sshfs) in a docker container, which is provided by kernel. I can load the modules easily in docker containers with privileged mode. However, if I would like to load the module when the container start and do not let it load other modules, is it possible?

Comment: How about mounting the sshfs from the host machine and then sharing the mount point to the container?

Comment: Btw, sshfs is not very good for productive usage, although it might be good if your container isn't a long lived one. For productive usage, I would use davfs.

Comment: In fact, I am to teach some students about transferring files over internet. It is nature to introduce sshfs when talking about sftp. I would like the students to try in a docker container.

Comment: Why docker containers instead of openvz instances: It is easier to set up and damage a docker container, and docker containers consume less disk.

Comment: Ok. sshfs is not a kernel module, it is a fuse filesystem. Fuse is the kernel module. Load in the host machine. Sshfs is a process which interacts with this kernel module, and provides the filesystem for it.

Comment: I tried to load fuse on the host machine, and tried to run sshfs in docker container. It shows `fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first`. I mounted another sshfs on host machine to ensure fuse is loaded. The sshfs command fails in docker container even if I created a new one after loading fuse on host machine.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the problem is actually loading modules?  If I do this:

```
% docker run -it ssh-test bash
root@090961bb6f3a:/project# sshfs xxxx@xxxx:/xxxx/xxxx /mnt
```

I get

```
fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first
```

The reason is that Docker containers have restricted capabilities.  The way to work around it is to run the container with

```
% docker run -it --cap-add SYS_ADMIN --device /dev/fuse ssh-test bash
```

which lets me use sshfs to mount volumes.